# Upload a video file from blackberry device to remote server

Tags: blackberry, video, file-upload

I want to upload a video file Through HTTP post. Some doubts arise are

- Is there any maximum file size limit when using HTTP post?
- Which are best file compression methods available for sending video file?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1) HTTP Post size limit is configured on the server.

2) Video file, unless you are sending raw uncompressed video data, is already packed by video codec, and won't be additionally compressed. Open DataOutputStream over HTTPConnection and write video-file bytes to this stream. When it is done close the stream. If you do not want to close stream, invoke flush() method.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Rafael Osipov said: when it comes to BB development there sometimes other points arise:

1) If you are using BES, then it is most likely there is a limit of data to be sent per an connection. This limit is set by BES administrator. The default value is smth around 200 KB (google on this to find out an exact value, and bear in mind it may depend on BES software version that a company uses). Since video files are usually large in size you may be a victim of this limit.

2) Some wireless network providers also have a limit of data to be sent per a connection. At least once I got such a case.

Since it's hard to predict whether your customers will get in these cases or not, my advice is to have some settings screen in the app that would allow users to enable "chunking". You'll have to split your file on set of smaller files (chunks) and send them sequentially creating a separate http connection per each chunk (size of chunk should be configurable by user). Then some script on your server recreates original file from chunks.

Comment: Thanks.for BES the maximum KB/Connection value is 1024.for details http://btsc.webapps.blackberry.com/btsc/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&externalId=KB10264&sliceId=SAL_Public&dialogID=36730425&stateId=0%200%2017307428#documentTop